# Why is form.addEventListener not a function?

Tags: javascript

Followed a tutorial, still says "form.addEventListener is not a function"
I've tried looking for the issue and still cant find it

```
const correctAnswers = ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'];
const form = document.querySelector = ('.quiz-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let score = 0;

    const userAnswers = [form.q1.value, form.q2.value, form.q3.value, form.q4.value];

    //check answers
    userAnswers.forEach((answer, index) => {
        if(answer === correctAnswers[index]){
            score += 25;
        }
    });

    console.log(score);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are trying to call the `.addEventListener` on a string (".quiz-for" in this case). You should be calling it on an HTML element (`form` in your case).

Change:

```
const form = document.querySelector = ('.quiz-form');
```

to:

```
const form = document.querySelector('.quiz-form');
```

Let me know if you need any more explanation.

Comment: Check your form first if it's not undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing querySelector properly

```
   const form = document.querySelector = ('.quiz-form');
```

should be changed to

```
   const form = document.querySelector('.quiz-form');
```